# Searching from all tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am developing a java app which can connect to oracle database and selecting column names from any tables, after selecting columns i have to query the data from those tables which the user select in my java app, now my question is how can i join all tables in the database so that query returns data successfully, i want to connect to any oracle schema to a specific, i will make the logic in java, but i am unable to find the query which can extract the data from all tables, i tried natural join among all tables but it has dependency of having same name of connecting columns. so i want to know any generic way which can work in all conditions.

Comment: Why do you want a join of all tables with same column name?

Comment: I was thinking about natural join but due to this dependency of same name i don't want to use this because it is not necessary that in every schema all tables has one same column name.

Comment: @WaleedRaza I suggest better use JPA for these kinds of projects or tasks as you would be able to easily map database objects.

Comment: "i want to know any generic way which can work in all conditions" This is a vast undertaking. Way beyond the scope of SO. There are existing architectural solutions to this, e.g, TOAD query builder, Crystal Reports, ElasticSearch and so on. Why not choose one of them?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, can you tell me in few words, what does it do ?

Comment: Is there any tool which joins tables automatically by just giving table names ??

Comment: just like query builder does in SQL developer i also want same automatic joining in java, is there any api which can do this ??

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned.. it seems that there are other tools out there that you probably should leverage prior to trying to roll your own *complex* solution.

With that said if you wish to roll your own solution you could look into using some of oracle's dictionary tables. Such as:

```
Select * from all_tables;

Select * from all_tab_cols;
```

Comment: user itself choose the columns and tables, i just want joining tables automatically.

Comment: @WaleedRaza in order to join the tables "automatically" you must develop the logic to determine how the tables are joined after your users select the columns and tables. I apologize, but I'm having trouble understanding the requirements so hopefully others can help.

Comment: just like query builder does in SQL developer i also want same automatic joining in java, is there any api which can do this ??

Comment: @WaleedRaza query builder does not automatically join the tables... you must specify how the tables should be joined.. therefore I can't imagine that an API exists. Perhaps someone else can prove me wrong though.